# The intersection of any set with the empty set is empty

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I know this may be routine and simple, but I'm not great at proofs and was wondering if someone could look at my solution and offer corrections or tips?

If A and B are sets, prove that

$ A  \cap \emptyset = \emptyset. $

My proof:

Let $x \in A \cap \emptyset $. Then x $\in A$ and $x \in \emptyset$. Thus x $\in$ $\emptyset$.

Let x $\in \emptyset$. Because $\emptyset \subset A $, x $\in$ A. Thus x $\in A \cap \emptyset$

Comment: Seems fine to me.

Answer (score 2):

It certainly works. Alternately, if you have proved that $\emptyset$ is a subset of every set and that $A\cap B\subseteq B$ regardless of $A,B,$ then you're basically done. There are other ways to proceed, as well, of course.